# Multi-threading windows phone application

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to make getting data make loading not in the ui thread but in background thread.
I've tried several examples from google, but it's still not working.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
{
    IList<Asana> asanasRepo = null;
    var asanasRepository = this.GetService<IAsanasRepository>();
    asanasRepo = asanasRepository.GetAllAsanas();

    Asanas = asanasRepo.Select(x => new AsanasListItemViewModel
    {
        AsanaId = x.AsanaId,
        AsanaLevel = InfrastructureHelper.GetLevel(x.AsanaLevel),
        CoverImagePath = string.Format("/Content/Images/{0}", x.CoverImageFileName),
        UsualAsanaTitle = x.UsualTitle,
        YogaAsanaTitle = x.YogaTitle
    }).ToObservableCollection();

    asanasDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        AsanasItems.Clear();
        AsanasItems = (from asana in Asanas
                       group asana by asana.AsanaLevel into c
                       orderby c.Key
                       select new Group<AsanasListItemViewModel>(c.Key, c)
                      ).ToObservableCollection();
    });
});
```

The main idea is lo load data from database not in the ui thread, but in background, when the data will be loaded render it to the ui.
I've tried something like the piece of code above, but it's not working. 
Can you help me with this?
Thank you!

Comment: What is failing? What error does it give you? What line?

Comment: No errors, just the list of items not rendered on UI.

Comment: have you made sure your binding works with a simpler example? also, try and run the code on the UI thread (ie. no within the ThreadPool)?

Comment: When I run on the UI thread everything works ok. Binding works just fine in this case. I just want to load data from data base in background thread, show the app main screen, and when the data will load, render it on the UI, using UI thread.

Comment: Does your class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Does the setter of the `AsanasItems` property raise the `PropertyChanged` event?

Comment: You should drop the threadpool, the dispatcher, and the BeginInvoke code and just use async/await.  You'd cut the above code by a third.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try initializing `AsanasItems` to an empty `ObervableCollection<..>` in the constructor and in your shown code do not assign a new collection to it, just use `AsanasItems.Add(..)` to add items one by one.

If it does not work you need to provide a minimal working sample for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Agree.. `AsanasItems.Add()` is required. OP is creating new collection altogether.

Comment: @YK1 It is not required, as long as the class implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @KooKiz: Yes, agree with you too - but that assuming `AsanasItems`'s containing class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and that `AsanasItems` is indeed a property. But we don't know that. I think OP has to clarify.